# Collection modified exception thrown when the collection wasn't modified

Tags: vb.net, enumeration

I'm getting an exception which I don't understand in this bit of code here:

```
Dim folderList As List(Of String) = _folderList

For Each folder In folderList

    destinationFolder = destinationFolder + "/" + folderName
    localFilePath = lbl_folderPath.Text + "/" + folder

    alterFolderList(localFilePath)

    ...

Next
```

I've got a global variable `_folderList` which I copy to another variable, `folderList`, as seen in the first line of my code. When the last method (`alterFolderList`) is called, it alters the variable `_folderList`. When debugging, as I reach the end of the `for each` for the first time (at `Next`) I get the exception that the collection was modified, when it actually wasn't because the method called doesn't change it. When debugging, after the method is called, I hover above the variable `folderList` and I see it changed and is now the same as `_folderList` but it shouldn't because the variable `folderList` is equaled to `_folderList` outside the `For Each` enumeration.

How does this happen? And how to work around this?

Comment: when you assign one list to another it is ByRef. you may need to copy the elements to a new list

Comment: sounds like _folderList is actually not a copy of folderLst **contents** but simply a copy of the reference, so when you change one, you change both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy the list you cannot assign it. You should copy the elements. Try this.

```
Dim folderList As New List(Of String)
folderList.AddRange(_folderList)
```